# Performance using include()

Tags: php, performance

In my projects I usually slice very much the code into files in order to have a more solid structure. Does the following 2 sample have some differences on performance?

```
# Sample 1
include('first.class.php'); # class first {}
include('second.class.php'); # class second {}

# Sample 2
class first {}
class second {}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does the following 2 sample have some differences on performance?

The approach you show is fine, and generally accepted, as long as you don't load hundreds or thousands of includes in every request.

This is also the required structure if you want to work with PHP's [autoloading](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

See http://pear.php.net/manual/en/pear2cs.introduction.php for the results of a require/include performance analysis. $searchengine will also give a lots of results.